# How to wire related models/controllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing an Ember application for storing "recommendations" about locations.

The user must select a location from a list (retrieved by a custom API), write a description, take a photo and make a POST with that data.

So I have a LocationModel and LocationController which retrieves the places from my API, display it on a list and allows the user to select one of them.
Then a DescriptionController and PhotoController which allow the user to write the description and take the photo.

I need to have each of these "parts" on individual controllers/models since I want them to reuse on others parts of my final app.

My Recommendation's model looks like this:

```
App.RecommendationModel = DS.Model.extend({
    location: DS.BelongsTo('location'),
    description: DS.BelongsTo('description'),
    photo: DS.BelongsTo('photo')
});
```

The corresponding recommendation template:

```
<section id="select-location">
  {{render "location" location}}
</section>
<section id="write-description">
  {{render "description" description}}
</section>
<section id="take-photo">
  {{render "photo" photo}}
</section>
<section id="send-recommendation">
  {{render "share"}}
</section>
```

Each 'section' has a button with a 'complete' action:

Eg:

```
App.DescriptionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    complete: function() {
      _saveDescription(this.get('value'));
    }
  }
});
```

My problem is how to "assemble" this parts in order to fulfil the RecommendationModel.

I think that the complete action should be something like:

```
App.DescriptionController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    complete: function() {
      recommendation.set('description', this);
    }
  }
});
```

Should the "complete" action be in the RecommendationController instead? If so, how should I wire each component?

Any other approach would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the 'global' `complete` action should be handled by the `RecommendationController` and each `complete` action should be handled by each controller (description, Photo and whatever).

What you can do is use the `needs` property in each controller that handles a part of the Recommendation:

```
needs: ['recommendation'],
```

And make the `RecommendationRoute` setup and use each controller and template of every part of the commendation like this:

```
App.RecommendationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super();
        var descController = this.controllerFor('description').set('content', model.get('description'));
        var photoController = this.controllerFor('photo').set('content', model.get('photo'));
        this.set('descController', descController).set('photoController', photoController);
        ...
    }, 

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this._super();
        this.render('description', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'description',
            controller: this.get('descController')
        });     
        this.render('photo', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'photo',
            controller: this.get('photoController')
        });
    }


});
```

This way, each controller of a part of the recommendation can handle its `complete` action. All use the same `recommendation` model and they can call the `RecommendationController` whenever necessary like this:

```
this.get('controllers.recommendation')
```

For instance, you'd do this to enable the `complete` action once all the parts of the recommendation have been completed.

Finally, you can bind the action of the 'global' `complete` action in an element inside the recommendation template, or just add another `render` call inside `renderTemplate` in `RecommendationRoute`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great! that did the trick. Now I've to find a way to decouple the 'recommendation' controller from the others controllers so I can reuse them later on my app. Thanks!